# What is the best way to limit number of threads running specific method?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

**Situation**

- I have web application
- I have class which does complicated mathematics computation
- Equations can take place from time to time depending on what request is
- Sometimes many threads starts this computation simultaneously
- When too many computations started, computer is become hanged (completely freeze = 99 CPU usage)

**My goal is**

My goal is to avoid hanging/freezing.

My guess is that it could be done by limiting number of simultaneous computations (probably to NUMBER_OF_CPU_CORES - 1)

**Question is**

What is the best way to reach this goal?

I know that there is [java.util.concurrent.Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html), but maybe there is better approach?

Comment: If my computer only has 1 core, are you not going to compute anything at all?

Comment: Can you reduce the priority of the threads that call your method?

Comment: @Jeffrey, of course it will be Math.min(1, NUMBER_OF_CPU_CORES - 1), just didn't want to pay attention to such things. In the production this web app will be executed on the server which has at least 4 cores, so this is not the case.

Comment: @MartinJames, yes I believe I can do this. You mean do not limit number of concurrent executions, just lower the priority for these threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Semaphore` looks like it is exactly what you want.

You'll probably want to put some logic in so that you use `Semaphore.tryAcquire` and return an error to the user if it cannot acquire a permit. If you use the blocking `acquire` method then you'll still wind up with a locked-up server.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the Java [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)  This should help with what you are trying to do.

Hope this helps...

Comment: +1 - This is the best approach, because it avoids you writing a bunch of low-level synchronization stuff.

Comment: (Maybe not always the best, but it's sure a good place to start! +1)

Comment: I don't have to control these threads. Because each thread is created by web app container (each request processed in it's own thread). So there is no low-level thread-related code for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably configure your application container to be limited to the number of request threads that you desire.

Barring that, the `Semaphore` is the perfect tool. Use the [`tryAcquire()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#tryAcquire%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method, and be sure to put a corresponding release in a `finally` block, like this:

```
if (permits.tryAcquire(7, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) 
  try {
    /* Do your computation. */
    compute();
  } finally {
    permits.release();
  }
else 
  /* Respond with "Too busy; try later," message. */
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the priority of the threads calling your method. If the rest of the apps on your box are not CPU-intensive, this will hardly affect your computations but responses to keypresses etc. should still be good.

Actually, I'm surprised that the box would hang/freeze even with a CPU-overload from multiple ready threads, (unless their priority has been raised).  Sluggish maybe...